# automatically linking socket shared library in *nix

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, solaris

I am learning network programming through the sample source codes from this link http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/textcode.html. During the compilation, just wondering why in Solaris environment, i have to manually link socket and nsl library in the make file but when in the linux machine, i dont need  to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation used: http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/solaris_linux_app.html

This is because linux's libc, the glibc (`-lc`, which is linked by default to all programs) includes socket part of POSIX; and `nis/nis+` dynamic libraries in linux are loaded dynamically by libc too.

But in Solaris, there are a lot of libraries with basic functionality, which are not in libc.
(libc, libucb, libmalloc, libsocket, libxnet, etc). I think, it was a design solution to allow user link only parts of API he needs.

In linux there are some basic libraries outside libc too: libaio, librt, libm.

With separate library it is easier to update only some parts of system; and it is possible to have several implementations (e.g. to provide greater compatibility/workarounds with older versions of UNIX) of some libraries coexisting in same system.

This question is discussed a lot, e.g. http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/KcxCHdLNpD6NANxmAt3b  http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/opensolaris-code/2007-January/010316.html

> > are seriously considering folding libnsl and libsocket into libc.
>
> It would be nice to move ONLY the current POSIX-based and other
> standards-based functionality (Unix98 etc.) libnsl+libsocket functions
> to libc and keep all the compatibilty-wrapper stuff in libnsl/libsocket
> to avoid that libc gets bloated with 20years of Unix
> backwards-compatibility workarounds

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. I also do believe that in the solaris systems, they tried to make the application as small as possible, so they prefer to use the dynamically linking (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~thomas/X/static-linking.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because in Linux, the entire networking API is implemented in `libc.so` which is linked into every C program by default, while in Solaris, its implemented in separate libraries.